# How to implement a Bootstrap Nav overlay effect

Tags: javascript, css, html, umbraco, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap navigation bar - that is working fine

Only the issue is that Im unable to implement an overlay on the NAV menu on mobile screens

Im working with Bootstrap and umbraco 7

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

            @foreach (var item in selection)
            {
                <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: @item.GetPropertyValue("navLinkColor")"></span>
            }

        </button>

        @Html.Partial("Shared/Logo")

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        @Html.Partial("Shared/MainNav")

        @Html.Partial("Shared/Links")

    </div>
</nav>
```

The code above is working fine on full Desktop screens - **But how do I implement a collapse overlay effect like the the image attached?**

[image].

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use @media queries with a max width for the mobile menu and a minimum width for the desktop view.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

```
 // Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
    // No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

    // Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
    @media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

    // Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
    @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

    // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
    @media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

    // Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
    @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Or you can use Sass:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(xs) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { ... }

// Example usage:
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .some-class {
    display: block;
  }
}
```